# Some text messages showing phone number not contact name

Tags: iphone, ios, messages, contacts

Suddenly, existing text strings are showing the contact number (not for all text messages), and not the contact name, on my iPhone 6. If I look for the person in my contacts, they are not listed. If I use their name to start a text discussion, their name and number show in the 'search' like if they were in the contacts.

Comment: Do you have a contact stored for all of the people you are messaging?

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this happen to me before. To fix it for myself I've had to disable `iCloud Contacts` and then enable them.

Although, it might be best to restart your device before disabling and then reenabling your iCloud contacts?

Steps:

1. Settings
2. Apple ID (top of settings)
3. iCloud (2nd set, 1st item)
4. Toggle contacts switch to disable
5. Delete from My iPhone
6. Toggle contacts switch to reenable

Comment: @steph Please mark as answered if it worked.

Answer (score 2):

My smart husband figured out this answer. The Apple Experts could not figure it out.

1. Go to Settings > General > Language > Select English (US) even if it is
   already selected.
2. Next you will see a popup at the bottom of the page: "Change to English (US)"/"Cancel"
3. Select "Change to English (US)"

Just wanted to post this if anyone else is having this problem.

Thanks,
Vivian